# Displaying in ListView with CustomArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using the CustomArrayAdapter to display the ListItem and to setTag. I am only setting the data to the list item textview but the id is also displaying in a seperate textview next to each data

how to avoid displaying that id?

[image]

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        Context mContext;
        int layoutResourceId;
        String data[] = null;
        String id[] = null;

        public CustomArrayAdapter(Context mContext, int layoutResourceId, String[] data, String[] id) {

            super(mContext, layoutResourceId, data);

            this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            this.mContext = mContext;
            this.data = data;
            this.id=id;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView==null){
                // inflate the layout
                LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            }


            String objectItem = data[position];


            TextView textViewItem = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_item);
            textViewItem.setText(objectItem);
            textViewItem.setTag(id[position]);

            return convertView;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you set content of data array ?

Comment: @zoherh in the constructor check my code in the question

Comment: Your data variable contains those ids I suppose. Your data string array contains Software Testing, 0001, etc,... so on, Check what data are you passing in

Comment: @Adnan Mulla yes you are right. thanks but dont know why it is like that :( I will look into that

Comment: You should accept the answer and close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data variable contains those ids I suppose. Your data string array contains Software Testing, 0001, etc,... so on, Check what data are you passing in